# How to dynamically change the position of an absolute tooltip base on the target element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a tooltip which basically shows a table (in my example below I used a large amount of text).
However I've wanted to change the position of the tooltip when you hover on the target element that is nearly at the corner of the screen.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps2btpmj/2/)

```
$("strong").on("mouseover", function(){
var $this = $(this),
strongText = $this.text();
$tooltipContainer.show();
$tooltipContainer.append('<span>'+ strongText + '</span>');
}).on("mousemove", function(mousePos){...
```

Comment: Have you tried using a library such as [Tether][1], which handles the positioning for you?  It's quite lightweight at only 23kb.


  [1]: http://github.hubspot.com/tether/

Comment: @michael thanks buddy, I wanted to not at least use any library/plugins. but i'll try to check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `mousemove` code a little to update `top` position if overlap is there like below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ps2btpmj/3/)

```
on("mousemove", function(mousePos){
    var overlap = mousePos.pageY + posSrollY + $tooltipContainer.height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
    $tooltipContainer.css({
        left: mousePos.pageX,
        top: mousePos.pageY + posSrollY - ( overlap > 0 && overlap )
    });
})
```